# Changes to PostgreSQL with the UPDATE, SET commands do not seem to persist

Tags: python, postgresql

I am to update rows of a Postgres DB table provided a condition is satisfied.

Suppose I have the `table "fruit"` and two of its columns are `"source"` and `"status"`.

I want to update the `"status"` from `"SOLD"` to `"EMPTY"` provided that the `"source"` is from `"FarmA"`.

For convenience lets just assume there is only one row in the table and the status is marked as `"SOLD"` for now.

The command that I wrote in python is:

```
postgres_update_query = "UPDATE fruit SET status = %s WHERE source = %s"
cursor.execute(postgres_update_query, ['EMPTY', 'FarmA']
```

The code works except the changes made to the table are not persistent.

When I check if the changes have been made before I close the connection I can see the changes have been applied.

However if I rerun the script it shows me that the changes have not been applied so it reruns the script fully again.

**From the PostgreSQL documentation is says the `SET` function:**

*If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back.
Once the surrounding transaction is committed, the effects will persist until the end of the session, unless overridden by another SET.*

I'm assuming when it says "...later aborted" it means closing a database connection.

So my question is, how can i make the updates persistent?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing the [`SET` clause of the `UPDATE` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) with the completely unrelated [`SET` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just need to commit after executing the command

```
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you terminate the database session before committing the transaction, it will be rolled back. That undoes the effects of the `UPDATE`.

`SET` changes a parameter for the duration of the database session, so it doesn't have any persistent effects.